# Connecting to PostgreSQL

Tags: c#, database, postgresql, npgsql

I use `Npgsql` to deal with `PostgreSQL` using C#. In order to connect to the database I wrote:

```
NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connstring);
conn.Open();
```

Open() is a `void` method. It doesn't return any value indicating whether it connect to the database or not.  I need to show the status `connected` or `not connected` in my client app. How to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can check value of `State` property:

```
NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connString); 
conn.Open(); 
if (conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open) 
       Console.WriteLine("Success open postgreSQL connection."); 
conn.Close();
```

Also event `StateChange` is available in version greater than 2.0 of this provider.

Comment: It is safer to use the NpgsqlConnection instance within using block. Thus you will always close the connection and release its related resources even in case of error behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Iterating on the answer of kmatyaszek and comment of Damyan Bogoev, this is what I did:

```
public async Task<bool> TestConnection()
    {
        await using (NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            await conn.OpenAsync();
            if (conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
                return true;
            else return false;
        }
    }
```